# Как задать статические объекты структуры в ней самой?

Tags: c++

На примере структуры `direction`

```
struct direction {
    int y, x;
    static const direction  //Как сделать так,
        NORTH = direction(-1,0), //Чтобы иницализация была в самой структуре
        SOUTH = direction(1, 0),
        WEST = direction(0, -1),
        EAST = direction(0, 1),
        NORTHEAST = direction::NORTH + direction::EAST; 

    direction(int y, int x) : y(y), x(x) {}

    direction operator+(const direction& right) const {
       direction result(*this);
       result.x += right.x;
       result.y += right.y;
       return result;
    }
};
```

Возможно ли сделать как-то так, не делая такого [enSO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35780171/6119618) чтобы без функций `constexpr` и без инициализации извне

Comment: Можно static методом возвращать `static const direction NORTH() {return direction(-1, 0);}`

Comment: @vladi я немного не правильно написал. Не хочу функции в принципе использовать, длинная очень запись у них

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Просто вынесите инициализацию из класса. Приведу пример для одного члена:

```
struct direction {
    ...
    static const direction NORTH;
};

const direction direction::NORTH = direction{0, 1};
```